# I designed a 4 Resistance biased amplifer, I used the Voltage divider MOSFET amplifer circuit for 2N7000

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, ltspice

[image: The Circuit]

[image: The simulation]

The blue lines in the simulation are the output and the green lines are the input, So I designed this amplifier while trying to limit Id to 200mA and I wanted to Bias the MOSFET such that I get no clipping with a change of ±20% of Vth. I wanted to know what I could change in this circuit to make it better or simpler. I calculated the capacitance for 20Hz and resistance of 67k. I don't know how to choose Rs, I chose 10 to increase the voltage range of the output (I was playing with the simulation).
I have been learning about MOSFETs on my own, so I wanted to try this out.

Comment: "simpler or better" depends on a lot of things. Is this an audio amp? RF amp? Battery supply or mains? What is the maximum harmonic distortion? How much does efficiency matter?

Comment: @Reinderien This is just as an exercise for a lab, I just wanted to know if I have made any mistakes, does the circuit have simply not being used to its full potiential. The task was to design a MOSFET amplifier and select a Q point to ensure no clipping with even ±20% variation in the Vth. I also have to justify the values of the resistors that I have chosen, I can pretty much justify everything except Rs, I don't know how to pick the value for Rs

Comment: @Redlion11 What are the design goals? Is there a voltage gain requirement? What are the details? (All of them, by the way.) These devices have quite a range for \$V_\text{TH}\$, by the way. so I'm not sure what "20% of Vth" is supposed to mean. It's not as though there is a precise value for it. Can you elaborate? Also, their Rds is like 5-6 Ohms, max. You are aware, yes?

Comment: @jonk, well the task was just to make a working amplifier with the 2N7000, the conditions they have specified is to ensure there is no clipping if there is a variation in the threshold voltage, a variation of +20% or -20%. There are no values mentioned, no gain requirements or use case scenario, the only goal is to demonstrate the amplifier mode of a MOSFET.

Comment: Look at the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF). Find Vgs(th) as being between 800 mV and 3 V. You tell me what 20% around that means.

Comment: @jonk, Ah, Sorry, they meant, 20% of the variation of the typical value, which is 2.1V

Comment: @Redlion11 Do you think that the 5-6 Ohm Rds might be "significant" vs your Rs choice?

Comment: @jonk, I am not really sure what you mean by that, but yes, Rds is quite significant when compared to 10ohms. Does this mean that the Rs should be >> Ron?

Comment: @Redlion11 Normally, you want the voltage gain to stay fixed. (Otherwise, you have signal-dependent distortion.) Also, there are thermal effects as well (which impacts mobility.) How much are you supposed to consider in all this? Do you care if there is a lot of distortion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116029/discussion-between-redlion11-and-jonk).

Answer (score 1):

This MOSFET in particular has a Vth of 0.8v min and 3V max that is a big range, you will have to handpick one when you build the circuit. What you can do is use the mean, which is around 2V, coincidentally, the SPICE model I have uses 2V as Vth.

The selection of the Source resistance has an impact on gain and DC point stability, the gain of the amplifier without considering source resistance or load resistance is roughly RD/(RS+1/gm), so in your circuit you have a gain of less than 20 because you have to add 1/gm to the source resistance since your source resistance is too low, if you increase the value of the source resistance then 1/gm will have less impact on the gain and linearity will improve, in which case gain can be estimated as RD/RS if RS >> 1/gm, so you can select the source resistance based on the required gain, remember that source degeneration increases linearity but lowers gain.

You can choose Rs on the basis of a specified gain, you can also select Rs on a specific voltage drop, for instance 1/4 VDD. What is your application?

These sort of one transistor amplifiers are far from what can be described as hi-end. Distortion is quite high. R1 and R2 are a bit low for my taste for a MOSFET amp.

Comment: My task was to make an amplifier with this MOSFET for an electronics lab, I just picked up the task online, so i can learn about MOSFETS in general. No real application was specified

Comment: gm is Forward transconductance right? So I should take the value of Gm as 320mS?

Comment: No, gm is 2ID/(VGS-VTH), so it depends on the drain current and on the gate source voltage.